# How to prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x)/x=L$

Tags: real-analysis

> 25. Let $f\colon(0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ be differentiable on $(0,\infty)$ and suppose that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f'(x)=L$.
>
> a. Show that for any $h>0$, $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h=L$.
>
> b. Show that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)} {x} =L$.

this is a differentiation question.

i don't know how to solve this question

Because it is Korean, it is difficult to deal with this cite.
So for me, it is not easy to write.

thank you

Comment: What are your thoughts? Is there anything your instructor has mentioned recently that would give you an inkling?

Comment: @ Pippo a isn't completely the definition of the derivative

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311152/applying-mvt-to-function-that-has-limit-of-its-derivative-given-when-x-to-infty, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1248374/let-f0-infty-to-r-be-differentiable-on-0-infty-and-fx-to-b-as, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1044668/if-fx-rightarrow-l-as-x-rightarrow-infty-infty-leq-l-leq-infty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) comes from the Mean Value Theorem. For $\varepsilon>0$ there is
$x_0$ such that $L-\varepsilon<f'(x)<L+\varepsilon$ for all $x\ge x_0$.
If $x\ge x_0$ then $(f(x+h)-f(x))/h=f'(x+\xi)$ where $0<\xi<h$. Then
$L-\varepsilon<f'(x+\xi)<L+\varepsilon$ etc.

Answer (score 0):

For b). Given $\epsilon>0$, find some $M$ such that $|f'(x)-L|<\epsilon$ for all $x\geq M$. Now for all $x>M$,
\begin{align*}
\left|\dfrac{f(x)}{x}-L\right|&=\left|\dfrac{f(x)-f(M)}{x-M}\dfrac{x-M}{x}-L+\dfrac{f(M)}{x}\right|\\
&=\left|f'(\xi_{x})\cdot\dfrac{x-M}{x}-L+\dfrac{f(M)}{x}\right|\\
&=\left|(f'(\xi_{x})-L)\cdot\dfrac{x-M}{x}+\dfrac{x-M}{x}\cdot L-L+\dfrac{f(M)}{x}\right|\\
&\leq\epsilon\left|1-\dfrac{M}{x}\right|+|L|\cdot\dfrac{|M|}{x}+\dfrac{|f(M)|}{x},
\end{align*}
taking $x\rightarrow\infty$ we have $\limsup_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left|\dfrac{f(x)}{x}-L\right|\leq\epsilon$, since $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, the result follows.