# Relation between $\lim_{x\to \infty} (f(x+h) - f(x)) /h$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x) $

Tags: real-analysis

Inspired from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2548583/72031) I want to ask if the converse also holds.

Let $f:(a, \infty) \to\mathbb {R} $ be differentiable on $(a, \infty) $.

> If for every $h>0$ the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{f(x+h) - f(x)} {h} $ exists and is equal to $L$ does the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f'(x) $ exist?

Using the mean value theorem it does not look like there is too much room for $f'(x) $ to oscillate, but I am not able to formulate the argument properly (at least for now) and therefore I guess that it might be possible that the limit of $f'(x) $ does not exist. But I have not found a counter-example.

The converse for the second part in linked question does not hold. That is, if $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{f(x)} {x} $ exists it does not necessarily imply that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f'(x) $ exists (check with $f(x) =\sin x$).

Comment: Try the function $f(x)=\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x}$

Comment: @Kelenner: so after all there is still too much room for oscillation of $f'(x) $ and my guess is correct. You may post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $f(x)=\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x}$ on $[1,+\infty[$ is a counter-example. As $f(x)\to 0$ if $x\to +\infty$, the limit exists for all $h>0$ (and is $0$). But the derivative of $f$ is $f^{\prime}(x)=-\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2}+2\cos(x^2)$, and has no limit if $x\to +\infty$.