# Let $f:[0,\infty[ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable on $(0,\infty)$ such that $f'(x) \to b \; as \; x \to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:[0,\infty[ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable on $(0,\infty)$ such that $f'(x) \to b \; as \; x \to \infty$

(a) Show that for any $h>0$ we have $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}=b$

(b) Show that if $f(x) \to a $ as $x \to \infty$ then $b = 0$

(c) Show that $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}=b$

I have no clue on how to approach this problem... I tried to show $h \to 0$ but I could not.

Comment: Hint for (a) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem.

Comment: I edited it. Now complete

Comment: (b) looks wrong to me, look at f(x) = x for example

Comment: @P.Koymans: why do you think it is wrong. It should be obvious that it is true.

Comment: @P.Koymans $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) \to a\implies \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x+k),\forall k\in\Bbb R\implies \lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x)=0$. in $f(x)=x$ we have $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)\ne a$(you have to remember that $\infty$ is not a number!!)

Comment: @ParamanandSingh i forgot to write the  limit

Comment: @Holo It was wrong, but changed later. See the edit history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\epsilon>0$, choose $M>0$ such that $|f'(u)-b|<\epsilon$ for $u\geq M$. Now fix an $h>0$, then for all $x>M$, we have $\left|\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-b\right|=|f'(\xi_{x,h})-b|<\epsilon$, this proves a).

Now assume the result in a), put $h=1$, for some $N>0$, we have $|f(x+1)-f(x)-b|<\epsilon$ for $x\geq N$. Now taking $x\rightarrow\infty$, we have $|b|=|a-a-b|\leq\epsilon$, this is true for all $\epsilon>0$, so $b=0$.

Comment: For c), I have answered someone else in the following link.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2548583/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to-infty-fx-l

Comment: for (a) don't I have to first show that $h \to 0$ because only then $f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0 } \frac{f(x+h)- f(x)}{h}$

Comment: I don't follow? In a), the limit taken is about $x\rightarrow\infty$, not $h\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: You are using $f'(x) = \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ in your first inequality am I right ? but isn't that true  only if $h \to 0$

Comment: I don't use $f'(x)=\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ and surely this inequality is not true.